# SQL Sorting number - ANDROID

Tags: android, sql, sorting

```
public static final String KEY_HIGH 

public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + DATABASE_TABLE + " (" +
                KEY_HIGH + " INTERGE);"
        );  
    }


public long createEntry(String high) {

    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();

    cv.put(KEY_HIGH, high);
    return ourDatabase.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, cv);
}



String[] columns = new String[]{KEY_HIGH,KEY_NAME};

Cursor c = ourDatabase.query(
                    DATABASE_TABLE, 
                    columns, null, null, null, null, KEY_HIGH + " DESC");
```

I am trying to sort by the column `KEY_HIGH`,  however, the result came out like this:

> 4
>   3
>   2
>   10
>   11
>   1

How do I sort them as numbers from highest to lowest?

thanks.

Comment: Is `KEY_HIGH` a number column? It seems it's sorted alphabetically.

Comment: Please show the `CREATE TABLE` statement for your table.

Comment: I added my onCreate and insert method

Comment: You create the `KEY_HIGH` column as Integer but in `createEntry` you are inserting String into it. Maybe that's the cause. Try changing the `high` parameter from `String` to `int` and see if anything changes.

Answer (score 0):

[From the Android docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#query(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)):

> public Cursor query (String table, String[] columns, String selection, String[] selectionArgs, String groupBy, String having, String orderBy)
>
> Added in API level 1
> Query the given table, returning a Cursor over the result set.
>
> **Parameters**
> *table*   The table name to compile the query against.
> *columns* A list of which columns to return. Passing null will return all columns, which is discouraged to prevent reading data from storage that isn't going to be used.
> *selection*   A filter declaring which rows to return, formatted as an SQL WHERE clause (excluding the WHERE itself). Passing null will return all rows for the given table.
> *selectionArgs*   You may include ?s in selection, which will be replaced by the values from selectionArgs, in order that they appear in the selection. The values will be bound as Strings.
> *groupBy* A filter declaring how to group rows, formatted as an SQL GROUP BY clause (excluding the GROUP BY itself). Passing null will cause the rows to not be grouped.
> *having*  A filter declare which row groups to include in the cursor, if row grouping is being used, formatted as an SQL HAVING clause (excluding the HAVING itself). Passing null will cause all row groups to be included, and is required when row grouping is not being used.
> *orderBy* How to order the rows, formatted as an SQL ORDER BY clause (excluding the ORDER BY itself). Passing null will use the default sort order, which may be unordered.
>
> **Returns**
> A Cursor object, which is positioned before the first entry. Note that Cursors are not synchronized, see the documentation for more details.
> See Also
> Cursor

Note that the final is named `orderBy`. This is where you can specify which column (or columns) to sort on. Also note that you do not need to include the "ORDER BY" keywords that you would use in a SQL statement.

Comment: I don't see any `ORDER BY` in his snippet and he already used `DESC` as the last parameter. What's the point?

Comment: @SamRad The point was to balance the other incorrect answers. After looking more closely at the OP, it appears that the problem lies elsewhere than the `query()` call, as you noted in your comment to the Q.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem.It has a very simple solution:

In your CREATE_TABLE statement do this: " INTEGER, "+KEY_HIGH+ //your remaining things.

Answer (score -1):

no need for the comma after the last null

```
Cursor c = ourDatabase.query(
            DATABASE_TABLE, 
            columns, null, null, null, null + " ORDER BY " + KEY_HIGH + " DESC");
```

Comment: The last parameter substitutes `ORDER BY` clause.

Comment: The Android Java docs explicitly state that the `orderBy` parameter excludes the words "ORDER BY".